# Prove that $12^{\text{th}}$ derivative of $f(x)$ at $x$=$0$ equals to $0$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, power-series

Prove or disprove Let $f(x) = \frac{x}{1+x^4} $ for every x    $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$. Then the  $12^{\text{th}}$ derivative of $f(x)$ at $x$= $0$ equals to $0$. It looks like I need to use Talyor series, but I cannot convert $f(x)$  to $\frac{1}{1-x}$ or to use any t to do so. I checked in a calculator, and the $12^{\text{th}}$ derivative is zero so it is a proof. How to approach it? (using integral looks a little bit complicated, not?)

Comment: The function is odd.

Comment: Alternative hint, if you want the Taylor series: You know the series for $\frac{1}{1-y}$. What can you plug into $y$ here to get $\frac{1}{1+x^4}$?

Comment: Are you sure you're looking for the derivative of $f(0)$? $f(0)$ is a constant, so its derivative is $0$. So is its 12th derivative. If you're asking for the 12th derivative of $f(x)$ at $x=0$, you should edit your question and clarify.

Comment: I agree with Dr. Momo. $f(0)$ is constant. $(D^{12}f)(0)$ is not the same that $D^{12}(f(0))$. You want the first one, not the second one.

Comment: It's sad that both answers took the hard way instead of using Ryszard Szwarc observation which makes the solution obvious.

Comment: @jjagmath What exactly is sad about providing other ways to get to the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $|x|<1$,

$$f(x) = \frac x{1+x^4} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^{4n+1}$$

Differentiate $12$ times, and observe that there is no integer $n$ which generates a $x^{12}$ term in the expansion, hence $f^{(12)}(0)=0$.

$$f^{(12)}(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n (4n+1) 4n (4n-1) \cdots (4n-10) x^{4n-11} \\
4n-11 = 12 \implies n=\frac{23}4 \not\in\Bbb Z$$

Answer (score 5):

If $|x|<1$, then
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\frac x{1+x^4}\\
&=x(1-x^4+x^8-x^{12}+\cdots)\\
&=x-x^5+x^9-x^{13}+\cdots,
\end{align}
and $\frac{f^{(12)}(0)}{12!}$ is the coefficient of $x^{12}$, which is $0$. Therefore, $f^{(12)}(0)=0$.